# How to deploy crowdsale contract

Tags: solidity

I created a token and crowd sale contract for that token together. But I have problems deploying it. When I wanted to deploy it, it gave me list of all the contracts in it and I didn't know which one to create... Should I deploy the crowd sale contract hoping it will also deploy the token too or am I to deploy each contracts one by one?

Comment: Can you Share the code?

Comment: Please give more information. Are you using any framework such as truffle? Is crowdsale contract from some contract library such as open zeppelin...etc

Answer (score 0):

Just simply check with [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/), run all the contracts and choose the correct one by which one shows all the methods of contracts.If you pick the wrong means Remix will show error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific implementation of your smart contract code. If your token and crowdsale contracts are separate and interconnected through the use of inheritance or an implementation of the ERC20 interface, then you may need to deploy the token contract first and then reference its address in the crowdsale contract to deploy it.

However, if your token and crowdsale contracts are combined into a single contract, then deploying that single contract should deploy both the token and crowdsale functionality.

In order to help you fully, it is better to show us your code